# Navigating between different folders on FTP server with Python

Tags: python, ftp, navigation

I would like to navigate between two different folders on the same FTP server in the same FTP session using Python's ftplib.

The basic script I wrote is as follows (gbname and gffname are assigned):

```
ensembl = FTP('ftp.ensemblgenomes.org')
ensembl.login()

ensembl.cwd("pub/fungi/current/genbank/")
ensembl.retrbinary('RETR ' + gbname, open(gbname, 'wb').write)

ensembl.cwd("pub/fungi/current/gff/")
ensembl.retrbinary('RETR ' + gffname, open(gffname, 'wb').write)

ensembl.quit()
```

This script tracebacks at the second cwd with the following error "ftplib.error_perm: 550 Failed to change directory.".

I understand why it tracebacks there and I can solve the issue by initiating two different FTP sessions, as follows:

```
ensemblgb = FTP('ftp.ensemblgenomes.org')
ensemblgb.login()
ensemblgb.cwd("pub/fungi/current/genbank/")
ensemblgb.retrbinary('RETR ' + gbname, open(gbname, 'wb').write)
ensemblgb.quit()

ensemblgff = FTP('ftp.ensemblgenomes.org')
ensemblgff.login()
ensemblgff.cwd("pub/fungi/current/gff/")
ensemblgff.retrbinary('RETR ' + gffname, open(gffname, 'wb').write)
ensemblegff.quit()
```

However, I was wondering whether, once I change directory to "pub/fungi/current/genbank/", it would be possible to change it to "pub/fungi/current/gff/" later (possibly going through the root folder in between?) in the same FTP session, without closing it and opening a new one.

Cheers,

Nicola

Comment: Have you tried? The reason you need 2 FTP connections to display 2 different directories at the same time is how FTP works. But there should be nothing preventing you from walking the directory tree (the parts you are allowed access to) as you please with either connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try prepending the backslash to the path - it stands for the root directory:

```
ensemblgff.cwd("/pub/fungi/current/gff/")
```